# Problema con Java Access, filtrar usuario

Tags: java, base-de-datos, ms-access

Tengo un problema y es que con Java Access no puedo traspasar datos introducidos de una ventana a otra.

Tengo un proyecto que es de un banco, en donde iniciara con una ventana de **Iniciar sesión**, pero no dejara pasar si **aun no ha hecho una cuenta** y tendrá la opción de **registrarse**. Después de eso permitirá iniciar sesión y saldrá una interfaz para poder abonar, ver su historial, etc.

Tengo colocado lo que es la ayuda de Access para poder crear una base datos y que al momento de crear cuenta se guarden todos mis datos.

Lo que quiero hacer es que mi **nombre de usuario pueda guardarse y pasar su nombre la interfaz para que los datos que vaya a introducir en la ventana de abonar y historial se queden a su nombre en la base de datos.**

Intente con un puntero que se almacenara el usuario y me salen excepciones que es null.
Intente también con un flujo de objetos y caracteres y tampoco.

```
try {
        declarax=conex.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT usuario, contraseña "+"FROM Clientes WHERE usuario = '"+txtUsuario.getText()+"' AND contraseña = '"+txtContraseña.getText()+"'";
        ResultSet resul = declarax.executeQuery(sql);
        while(resul.next()){
            usuario = ""+resul.getString(1);
            contraseña = ""+resul.getString(2);
        }
        if(txtUsuario.getText().equals(usuario) && txtContraseña.getText().equals(contraseña)){
            vt.txtE.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER); vt.txtE.setBounds(160, 110, WIDTH, WIDTH);
            vt.txtE.setText("Inicio sesión correctamente");vt.setVisible(true);
            log=1;
            
            dispose();
        }else{
            ve.txtEx.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER); ve.txtEx.setBounds(160, 110, WIDTH, WIDTH);
            ve.txtEx.setText("Usuario y/o Contraseña incorrectas");ve.setVisible(true);
        }
    }catch(SQLException er){
            ve.txtEx.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);ve.txtEx.setBounds(160, 110, WIDTH, WIDTH);
            ve.txtEx.setText("Error al cargar los datos");ve.setVisible(true);
        
    }
```

Este código es cuando busco sobre la base datos el usuario y la contraseña.
Intente hacer algo parecido pero no me salio. No se si puedan ayudarme con un ejemplo de como poder pasar el nombre de usuario.

**Buenas noches y gracias.**

Método para abrir la nueva ventana:

```
private void btnAceptarMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    VentenaMenu vp= new VentenaMenu();         
    vp.setVisible(true);
    dispose();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);     
}
```

Comment: Primero, deberías parametrizar tu consulta para que sea más segura. Segundo, ¿Dónde está el método que abre tu nueva ventana?

Comment: Pido disculpas, me di cuenta que este es un proyecto "viejo" donde llamo a otra ventana que tengo para que salte que inicie correctamente, pero podemos trabajar con este.
`private void btnAceptarMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
        VentenaMenu vp= new VentenaMenu();
        vp.setVisible(true);
        dispose();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    } `

Comment: He adjuntado una posible respuesta, me avisas si te funciona

Comment: Me medio funciono, en vez de ser lo que yo agrego en el txtUsuario, que es lo que quiero que muestre, solamente sale null

Comment: ¿Podrías adjuntar el código de tu botón correcto y de Nueva Ventana?

Answer (score 0):

Bien, en tu pregunta dices que quieres mostrar el dato recibido desde la Ventana A. (Le pongo A para ejemplificar nada más).

Lo que puedes hacer, es crear una variable y recibir el valor para luego pasarlo al nuevo objeto:

```
private void btnAceptarMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    String usuario = txtUsuario.getText();
    VentenaMenu vp= new VentenaMenu(usuario);         
    vp.setVisible(true);
    dispose();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);     
}
```

Ahora, en el código de tu ventana debes modificar el que existe:

```
public VentenaMenu(String arg) {
    initComponents();
    lblSaludo.setText("Hola: "+arg); //suponiendo que tienes un label creado
}
```